# WCF endpoint address

Tags: wcf, endpoint

Does anyone know if the endpoint used for the service request can be accessed from within the service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.EndpointDispatcher.EndpointAddress
```

That should do the job.

Comment: Thanks for the amazingly quick answer.

Comment: And thanks to whoever corrected my spelling of endpoint in the description. ;)

Comment: 1st Msg - No probs ;).  2nd Msg - It's things like that which make StackOverflow sooo good.

Comment: Yeah, I'm in the middle of a 6 month project to develop a WCF service and WPF UI.  Having never really used either commercially Stack Overflow has been invaluable.